How to enable the compact path filter in Jetty
I'm trying to fix AMBIGUOUS_EMPTY_SEGMENT errors in a Spring Boot application that builds on embedded Jetty. I think I want to use https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-12/org/eclipse/jetty/rewrite/handler/CompactPathRule.html but the documentation doesn't really explain how to enable the rule.
I have already allowed this violation and added a listener for violations. The listener never gets triggered. If I remove the custom Uri compliance, the listener starts getting hits. Seems like rewriting the URLs is easier than really allowing the empty path segments. There is a ticket about this on Jetty https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/11448
                HttpConnectionFactory connFac = conn.getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);
                Set<UriCompliance.Violation> violations = new HashSet<>();
                violations.add(UriCompliance.Violation.AMBIGUOUS_EMPTY_SEGMENT);
                UriCompliance customUriCompliance = new UriCompliance("Custom", violations);
                connFac.getHttpConfiguration().addComplianceViolationListener(new ComplianceViolation.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplianceViolation(ComplianceViolation.Event event) {
                        ComplianceViolation.Listener.super.onComplianceViolation(event);
                        System.err.println("COMPLIANCE VIOLATION");
                    }
                });

                connFac.getHttpConfiguration().setUriCompliance(customUriCompliance);

Most of the semi-related questions on Stack Overflow talk about editing various XML files, none of which seem to exist in a Spring Boot project.

The CompactPathRule cannot fix a UriCompliance violation.
That kind of violation is fundamental and no dispatching / handling of the request occurs.
Your code for adjusting the UriCompliance configuration is the right path to go down.
But be aware that this is 100% not supported by Jetty 12/ee10, Servlet 6 spec, REST spec, and Spring Boot.
